# How to delete an intermediate directory in windows using cmd?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, directory, filesystems

For example to go from this:

```
directory1/
   101/online/img1.png
   102/online/img2.png
   103/online/img3.png
```

To this:

```
 directory1/
   101/img1.png
   102/img2.png
   103/img3.png
```

In this example, `101` (and `102`, `103`...) directories contain only a single directory `online`, which is always of the same name. However, `online` directory may contain multiple files inside, but no directories.

I am looking for an automated way to manipulate my files like that, as I have a big list of such cases. I am looking for a Windows Command Prompt or Powershell solution.

Comment: So you need a way to enumerate file system items in folders, move them, and finally deleting a directory - definitely something either cmd or powershell is capable of. Which part do you need help with?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I am new to cmd, I can only navigate and do simple tasks. I think I will need help with all of the parts.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I don't need to enumerate them. the file names are already there. Just move and delete in a loop.

Comment: I was talking about the immediate parent folders (`101`, `102`, `103`, etc) :-)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Amm yeah, I need to consider all of the folders, however many there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New answer and **updated**

This from the command line:

```
pushd directory1
for /D %D in (*) do move /Y %D\online\*.* %D && rmdir /s /q %D\online
popd
```

Or this from a cmd file:

```
pushd directory1
for /D %%D in (*) do move /Y %%D\online\*.* %%D && rmdir /s /q %%D\online
popd
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Should I run this command from the directory1 in cmd? Or from the parent directory of directory1?

Comment: Oh pushd saves it into the memory and %D is used to access it from the memory right?

Comment: Ok I got it, from the parent directory